# Sort Multi Dimensional Array on Index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I need to **find the Positions of class**.
I have Multidimensional Array which is below :

```
var myData = {
      0 : {
           stdid : 1,
           marks : 98,
           pos   : ,
          },
      1 : {
          stdid : 2,
           marks : 90,
           pos   : ,
          },
      2 : {
           stdid : 3,
           marks : 77
           pos   : ,
            },
      3 : {
           stdid : 4,
           marks : 98,
           pos   : ,
          },
      4 : {
           stdid : 5,
           marks : 66,
           pos   : ,
          },
 }
```

I need this Array to fill the position of each index like this

```
var myPositionData = {
      0 : {
           stdid : 1,
           marks : 98,
           pos   : 1,
          },
      1 : {
           stdid : 2,
           marks : 90,
           pos   : 2,
          },
      2 : {
           stdid : 3,
           marks : 77
           pos   : 3,
            },
      3 : {
           stdid : 4,
           marks : 98,
           pos   : 1,
          },
      4 : {
           stdid : 5,
           marks : 66,
           pos   : 4,
          },
 }
```

What I am trying to do is calculating positions of class.

Comment: Step 1: Use an array. There are no arrays in your code at all, single- or multi-dimensional. Those are non-array objects.

Comment: Step 2: Show us what you've tried and what it's doing that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is an object not an array. If you want to use an array have a look at this

```
var myPositionData = [{
    stdid: 1,
    marks: 98,
}, {
    stdid: 2,
    marks: 90,
}, {
    stdid: 3,
    marks: 77,
}, {
    stdid: 4,
    marks: 98,
}, {
    stdid: 5,
    marks: 66,
}]

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.marks < b.marks) return 1;
    if (a.marks > b.marks) return -1;
    return 0;
}
myPositionData.sort(compare);

var currentPositions = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < myPositionData.length; i++) {
    myPositionData[i].pos = currentPositions;
    if (!(i < myPositionData.length - 2 && compare(myPositionData[i], myPositionData[i + 1]) == 0)) {
        currentPositions++;
    }
}
console.log(myPositionData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution here. Just iterate the array and add the position key directly.

```
for(var key in myData) {
  if(myData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myData[key].pos = key+1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = count($myData);
for($a=0; $a<$total;$a++)
{
  $myData[$a]['pos'] = $a+1;
}
```